# w3css cell rows overlapping

Tags: html, css, w3.css

I have a webpage where the header is defined in a user control. (I'm using w3css as my framework.) I have the user control placed in a another page. I have it wrapped in div tag with the *w3-cell-row* class. Then I have another div below that with my main content. It is also wrapped in a div tag with the *w3-cell-row* class. The problem is that the main div does not stack under the header div. It slides up underneath the header. Does it have anything to do with the header being a user control? What am I missing? See code below and screenshot below that.

**My header control:**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Header.ascx.cs" Inherits="Header.controls.Header" %>
<%@ Register assembly="DevExpress.Web.v16.1, Version=16.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" namespace="DevExpress.Web" tagprefix="dx" %>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/w3.css" />
<style type="text/css">
    html, body {
        margin:0; padding:0
    }

</style>



<%--Large Screens--%>
<div class="w3-hide-small" style="width:100%; margin:0px; position:fixed; top:0; background-color:white;">

    <div class="w3-cell-row">
        <div class="w3-cell" style="display: inline-block; float:left; height:25px;">
            <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~\images\Header.png" />
        </div>

        <div class="w3-cell" style="text-align: right; vertical-align: top; border: none; background-color:white; display: inline-block; float:right;">
            &nbsp;<asp:Label CssClass="w3-hide-medium" ID="lblLogin" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="10pt" ForeColor="#1F51A0" Font-Names="Arial">Welcome User</asp:Label>
            &nbsp;<span style="color: white; font-weight: bold">|</span>&nbsp;
                <asp:Label CssClass="w3-hide-medium" ID="lblLastLoginDate" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="10pt" Font-Names="Arial"
                    ForeColor="#1F51A0">Last Login</asp:Label>
            &nbsp;<span style="color: white; font-weight: bold">|</span>&nbsp;
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lbLogout" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" Font-Size="10pt" Font-Names="Arial"
                    Font-Underline="False" ForeColor="#1F51A0" OnClick="lbLogout_Click" Font-Bold="true">Logout &nbsp;</asp:LinkButton>
        </div>
    </div>

        <div class="w3-cell-row" style="text-align:right; vertical-align:bottom; background-color:#2c4182">

            <dx:ASPxMenu ID="ASPxMenu1" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" ForeColor="White" GutterWidth="0px" Paddings-Padding="0" BackColor="#2c4182" AppearAfter="0">

                <Paddings Padding="0px" />
                <ItemStyle>
                    <SelectedStyle BackColor="#3366CC" Border-BorderStyle="None" Border-BorderWidth="0" Font-Bold="True">
                    </SelectedStyle>
                    <HoverStyle BackColor="#3366CC"></HoverStyle>
                </ItemStyle>
                <SubMenuItemStyle BackColor="#2c4182" >

                    <HoverStyle BackColor="#3366CC">
                    </HoverStyle>

                </SubMenuItemStyle>
                <SubMenuStyle GutterWidth="0px" />
                <Border BorderStyle="None" />
            </dx:ASPxMenu>
        </div>
    </div>

   <%-- Small Screens--%>
<div class="w3-hide-medium w3-hide-large w3-cell-row">
    <div style="text-align: left; vertical-align: bottom; background-color: #2c4182;">

            <dx:ASPxMenu ID="ASPxMenu2" runat="server" Orientation="Vertical" Font-Bold="False" ForeColor="White" GutterWidth="0px" Paddings-Padding="0" BackColor="#2C4182" AppearAfter="0">

                <ClientSideEvents CloseUp="function(s, e) {
ASPxMenu2.SetSelectionItem(null);
}" />

                <Paddings Padding="0px" />
                <ItemStyle>
                    <SelectedStyle Border-BorderStyle="None" Border-BorderWidth="0" Font-Bold="True">
                    </SelectedStyle>
                    <HoverStyle BackColor="#3366CC"></HoverStyle>
                </ItemStyle>
                <SubMenuItemStyle BackColor="#2c4182">

                    <HoverStyle BackColor="#3366CC">
                    </HoverStyle>

                </SubMenuItemStyle>
                <SubMenuStyle GutterWidth="0px" />
                <Border BorderStyle="None" />
            </dx:ASPxMenu>
        </div>
</div>
```

**My webpage:**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Homepage.aspx.cs" Inherits="Website.Homepage" %>

<%@ Register Src="Controls/Header.ascx" TagName="Header" TagPrefix="uc1" %>
<%@ Register Src="Controls/Footer.ascx" TagName="Footer" TagPrefix="uc2" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="DevExpress.Web.v16.1, Version=16.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" Namespace="DevExpress.Web" TagPrefix="dx" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head runat="server">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/w3.css" />
    <title>Home</title>
    <style>
        .newStyle1 {
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: medium;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .ChartHeaders {
            font-family: "Franklin Gothic Medium", "Arial Narrow", Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: small;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .auto-style2 {
            text-align: center;
            font-size: xx-large;
            color: #C0C0C0;
        }

        html, body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        html {
            height: 100%;
        }

        body {
            min-height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <%--Header--%>
        <div class="w3-cell-row w3-mobile">
            <div class="w3-cell w3-col s12 m12 l12">
                <uc1:Header ID="Header1" runat="server" />
            </div>
        </div>


        <%--Main--%>
        <div class="w3-cell-row w3-mobile">
            <%--Left Side Bar--%>
            <div class="w3-cell w3-col l2 m2 s12" id="SideBar">
                <%--Message Center--%>
                <dx:ASPxRoundPanel ID="ASPxRoundPanel1" runat="server" ShowCollapseButton="true" Width="100%" Height="50%" HeaderText="Message Center">

                    <PanelCollection>
                        <dx:PanelContent runat="server"><span style="font-size: large">This is where you can display messages to the field.</span></dx:PanelContent>
                    </PanelCollection>

                </dx:ASPxRoundPanel>

                <%--Schedule--%>
                <dx:ASPxRoundPanel ID="ASPxRoundPanel3" runat="server" ShowCollapseButton="true" Width="100%" Height="50%" HeaderText="Upcoming Events">

                    <PanelCollection>
                        <dx:PanelContent runat="server"><span style="font-size: large">This will display upcoming events, deadlines, etc.</span></dx:PanelContent>
                    </PanelCollection>

                </dx:ASPxRoundPanel>

            </div>

            <%--Main Dashboard--%>
            <div class="w3-cell w3-col s12 m10 l10 w3-mobile" id="Dashboard">

                <dx:ASPxRoundPanel ID="ASPxRoundPanel2" runat="server" ShowCollapseButton="false" ShowHeader="false" Width="100%" Height="100%">
                    <PanelCollection>
                        <dx:PanelContent runat="server">
                            <div class="auto-style2">
                                Dashboard
                            </div>
                        </dx:PanelContent>
                    </PanelCollection>
                </dx:ASPxRoundPanel>

            </div>
        </div>

        <%--Footer--%>
        <div class="w3-cell-row">
            <uc2:Footer ID="Footer" runat="server" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

[Screenshot showing problem I'm having](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXuIk.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate each component with a `<div class="w3-container">` . Since w3css works with containers, if you do not differentiate the navbar and upcoming events divs in different containers, your browser will group them all together in the same container and hence it will overlap with each other.